# stripping value labels from imported SPSS `.sav` data

Tags: r-haven

In `haven` docs, I've seen examples of how `zap_labels()` will strip value labels from variables. In each case in the docs, the variable used in the example was created using an `R` assignment operator (`<-`) to directly create a vector (e.g. image below, via: https://haven.tidyverse.org/reference/zap_labels.html ).

[image: zap labels vector creation]

However, I'm trying to use `zap_labels()` on data I've imported using haven's `read_sav()`, and it doesn't seem to be working as I expect.

---

Code: (I'm on Windows 10):

I import a `.sav` file using `haven` like so:

```r
June18 <- read_sav("C:/ ... filename.sav", 
  user_na = FALSE) %>% 
  as_factor()
```

---

The variable I'm exploring is `V1Q1_W35`

Attributes:

```
attributes(June18$V1Q1_W35)
```

Output:

> $levels
> [1] "Very fair"       "Somewhat fair"   "Not very fair"   "Not fair at all" "Refused"

---

In the original `.sav` file, value label mappings for `V1Q1_W35` look like this:
[image: value label mappings]

---

So, per my understanding, if I do `zap_labels()` to `V1Q1_W35`, I should see the original numbers in the data like `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` and `99`.

However, when I do the following, I still see value labels.

```
attributes(zap_labels(June18$V1Q1_W35))
```

Output:

> $levels
> [1] "Very fair"       "Somewhat fair"   "Not very fair"   "Not fair at all" "Refused"

---

**So my question is: in this situation (trying to see the different levels), what should I be doing to see the original numbers in the data instead of the value labels they are mapped to?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because ehen importing your data, you convert it to a factor, which in this case just keeps the labels and gets rid of the numbers.

So you could either don‘t use the `as_factor` command when reading in your data before applying the `zap_labels` command or you can directly convert your variables to numeric during import by using `as.numeric`. You can of course also choose to apply this only to a subset of columns where tjis makes sense.